# call javascript method from codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to call this **javascript** function from asp.net **codebehind pageload**..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function abc() {
                 alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
     }
  </script>
```

Is it possible to pass an integer array in to javascript function from asp.net codebehind pageload?

Comment: Follow this article on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try below code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "abc", "abc();", true);
}
```

**1. Update > Passing string parameter :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var message = "hi";
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "abc", "abc('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

JavaScript Method with string parameter :

```
function abc(message) {
    alert(message + ", I am an alert box!");
}
```

**2. Update > Passing string parameter and numeric array  to JS method:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] numbers = { 10, 20, 30 };

    string serializedNumbers = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(numbers);

    var message = "hi";
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "abc", "abc('" + message + "', " + serializedNumbers + ");", true);
}
```

JavaScript Method with string and numeric array parameters:

```
function abc(message, numbers) {

    alert(message + ", I am an alert box!");
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        alert(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to pass parameters into javascript function..       When I use                  System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "abc", "abc('hai');", true);                        it is working ... But when i use                                      string s = "Hai";      System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "abc", "abc(s);", true);                          It's not working....

Comment: You can rewrite your function like following
function abc(message){alert(message);} to pass message as argument

Comment: that's common understanding. Question was how to call JS method from code behind. By the way thanks for the information. I will update it.

Comment: I have a function like                                               $(function donutchartcreation(numbers) {       
          alert(numbers[1]);                                           } Here number[1] can not be identified.. Can you plz help me to find the reason?

Comment: @SpiderCode yes that is thing of common understanding, that's y write in comment, anyway grate and to the point answer thanks I can not leave it without up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

### Regular Page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "abc" + UniqueID, "abc();", true);
}
```

### Ajax Page

You need to use ScriptManager if you use ajax.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), 
     "abc" + UniqueID, "abc();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    Dim script As String = String.Format("abc()", "")
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), UniqueID, script, True)
```

Or simply

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "abc", "alert('Hello! I am an alert box!')", true);
```

Comment: hi..I use                         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "thisScript", "abc()", true);                                       But it is not working...

Comment: Try changing `abc()` to `abc`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a JavaScript function from the codebehind, but you can return a response that includes JavaScript that invokes the function when the page loads in the browser.  Just make sure that your page includes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abc() {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
    abc();
</script>
```

That could be either as part of the ASPX page or you could register it as a script block in the codebehind.