# Why is my alert not popping up? Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, alert

My alert does not pop up. When I debug this with a breakpoint, this line is executed

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + " We don't seem to have this user registered. Please try again " + "') ; location.href='Login.aspx'</script>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ***don't*** needs to be escaped.

This can be done as follows:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + " We don\\'t seem to have this user registered. Please try again " + "') ; location.href='Login.aspx'</script>");
```

It should pop up now.

Answer (score 0):

see below code sample to get the alert :

**Code Behind :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "abc", "abc();", true);
}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function abc(message) {
    alert(message + ", I am an alert box!");
}
```

Have a look at [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415920/call-javascript-method-from-asp-net-codebehind-pageload/20416197#20416197) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also..

```
 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Your Message.');", true);
```